# Adding a new webservice in a struts2 web application

Tags: web-services, struts2, netbeans-7

I'm working on Netbeans IDE 7.0.1, and these are the libraries I am using:

- antlr-2.7.6.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.8.1.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.jar
- commons-digester-2.0.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- ejb3-persistence.jar
- freemarker-2.3.15.jar
- hibernate-annotations-3.2.0.ga.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
- hibernate-core.jar
- hsqldb.jar
- javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
- jta-1.1.jar
- log4j-1.2.15.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar
- ognl-2.7.3.jar
- slf4j-api-1.4.2.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.4.2.jar
- struts2-config-browser-plugin-2.1.6.jar
- struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar
- struts2-dojo-plugin-2.2.3.1.jar
- xwork-core-2.1.6.jar

I created a Struts2 web application, and I added a web service in a new package *webservice* by using Netbeans wizard; in my `struts.xml` I used the following:

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/YouSportWS*"/>
```

but when I test my web service by clicking *Test Web Service* in Netbeans contextual menu, I get in my browser the following error:

```
Struts Problem Report

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

Messages:   
controller.MyWebService
Unable to instantiate Action, controller.YouSportWS, defined for 'YouSportWS' in namespace '/'controller.YouSportWS
File:   org/glassfish/web/loader/WebappClassLoader.java
Line number:    1.519

Stacktraces

Unable to instantiate Action, controller.YouSportWS, defined for 'YouSportWS' in namespace '/'controller.YouSportWS
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:307)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:388)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:187)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:478)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controller.YouSportWS
        org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1519)
        org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1369)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:146)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.getClassInstance(ObjectFactory.java:96)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:149)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:139)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:109)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:288)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:388)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:187)
        org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
        org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:478)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
        com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

What's wrong in my settings?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern should be a real regex:

```
excludePattern="YouSportWS.*"
```

See the [documentation regarding exclusions](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/webxml.html).

Comment: I tried using
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="YouSportWS.*"/>
and 
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/YouSportWS.*/"/>
but it doesn't work yet...

Comment: I'm using struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar.

Comment: @AlexGpeppe Deploying to what context? Same behavior if you use `.*YouSportWS.*`?

Comment: Yes, I got the same behaviour. What do you mean with your first question?

Comment: @AlexGpeppe I mean are you deploying to the root context, or a named app context?

Comment: My struts web application root is at http://localhost:8080/ACL-WebApp/ and my web service endpoint is at http://localhost:8080/ACL-WebApp/YouSportWS

Comment: @AlexGpeppe Any other details you can provide? The behavior works fine for me under a non-root context using `.*foo.*`. What plugins are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any particular plugin.
What if I move my struts web application from the root context to a named context? Something like this:
ACL-WebApp/Struts/ and ACL-WebApp/WebService/

Could this solve my problem? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: @AlexGpeppe As I said, the behavior works fine for me. Could you edit your question and add the libraries you're deploying?